# GROUP_CONCAT for similar records in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I have a the following query in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT sale_order.id,sale_order.name AS orden, now()::date AS hoy,
sale_order.create_date::date, split_part(res_partner.name,' ',1) AS cliente,
res_partner.email,sale_order.amount_total,res_currency.name FROM
sale_order,product_pricelist,res_currency,res_partner WHERE 
sale_order.partner_id = res_partner.id 
AND sale_order.pricelist_id = product_pricelist.id
AND product_pricelist.currency_id = res_currency.id 
AND sale_order.state = 'sent' 
ORDER BY sale_order.create_date DESC;
```

and the resulting set is looks like this:

```
658, SO658, 2015-05-17, 2015-04-16, Alejandro, some@email.com, 14272.00, MXN
654, SO654, 2015-05-17, 2015-04-15, Edgar, one@email.com, 4994.96, MXN
653, SO653, 2015-05-17, 2015-04-15, Edgar, one@email.com, 3007.29, USD
```

As you can see, the 2nd and 3rd records are somehow duplicated, somehow because its the same user but has different id, order name, dates, etc.

How I would like to do is disregard the dates and amounts but GROUP_CONCAT the order names, so the end result would look like this:

```
SO658, Alejandro, some@email.com
SO653 & SO654, Edgar, one@email.com
```

As you can see, I dropped the unnecessary columns and GROUP_CONCAT the order names that belongs to the same user so in the end each user would have only one record showing all their order names.

How can I do this in PostgreSQL?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit hard trying out a query without table definitions or an SQL fiddle, but :

You can `GROUP BY` both `cliente` and `email` and then use `array_agg`, which will return an `ARRAY`. You can use `string_agg(sale_order.name, ' & ')` if you want really want a string, but arrays are usually easier to work with.

```
SELECT array_agg(sale_order.name) AS orden,
       split_part(res_partner.name,' ',1) AS cliente,
       res_partner.email
FROM  sale_order,product_pricelist,res_currency,res_partner
WHERE sale_order.partner_id = res_partner.id 
  AND sale_order.pricelist_id = product_pricelist.id
  AND product_pricelist.currency_id = res_currency.id 
  AND sale_order.state = 'sent'
GROUP BY cliente, email;
```

Comment: I thought about using array_agg but I'm using version 8.4 (CentOS 6.5)

Comment: `array_agg()` was introduced in 8.4 . Also, please specify your PostgreSQL version in your question (especially when using older versions), it'll be easier for people to help you.

Comment: Sorry, this was my first question. BTW any way to remove the () that array_agg seems to put and add a space after each , ?

Comment: To answer my own question so it is here for historic purposes, just replace with `array_to_string(array_agg(sale_order.name),', ') AS orden`

Comment: @AntonKrall: 8.4 is no longer maintained. You should really plan an upgrade to a maintained (= supported) version (e.g. 9.4) **now**.

Comment: The problem is that 8.4 seems to be the one available via yum for CentOS 6.5 and I know I can upgrade outside of yum but since the server is very stable I was waiting for the yum repos to be updated.